# Installing another Eclipse on Mac

Tags: eclipse

I already have Eclipse installed on my computer, Mac, for school and I would like to install second Eclipse for my personal use. Can I install two same version of Eclipse on my computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. You don't have to install eclipse, eclipse can copy to a location. But you can switch the workspace during starting eclipse, then you have your own developer environment too.